# .htaccess not removing .php extension from url

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let me start by saying that I found a lot of scripts to put into the .htaccess file and I made a note of all that worked EXACTLY the way I wanted them to.

So for example if I had a file named test.php in my htdocs folder and I went to localhost/test.php, I want the file to be rewritten as localhost/test in the browser.

I found 2 .htaccess files which do this and I showed them below, but the problem with them is whenever I try to use a form to insert data into a MYSQL database I ALWAYS get blank fields.

This is the first one

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

This is the second one

```
# Turn on the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine  on
# If the request doesn't end in .php (Case insensitive) continue processing rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
# If the request doesn't end in a slash continue processing the rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
# Rewrite the request with a .php extension. L means this is the 'Last' rule
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

I then found some scripts which worked exactly like a charm after searching for hours and hours then yesterday I went to shower, came back and they weren't working. (I deleted the old .htaccess file, created a new one, restarted mysql and apache, cleared browser data etc and the .htaccess still wouldn't work) and they worked how I wanted them to before I went to shower.

These 2 worked before (No I did not put them both in the .htaccess file at the same time)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

The second one

```
# Options is required by Many Hosting
Options +MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

# For .php & .html URL's:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

So now they ONLY work if I remove the .php from the url manually but I don't want it done like that, or I don't want to manually change all my links in my php documents from having the .php extension and I wanted to use either one of them because when I used a form to insert data to MYSQL the data actually showed up and the fields weren't blank.

I also found one that adds a trailing slash, so localhost/test.php becomes localhost/test/ but it worked once and now it doesn't work anymore, but with that one if I use a form to insert data to MYSQL database the fields are blank as well.

```
# Apache Rewrite Rules
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

# Add trailing slash to url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Remove .php-extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php 

# End of Apache Rewrite Rules
```

Like I said I found and made note of the ones that worked EXACTLY how they were supposed to but now they aren't working, does anyone know why? Or how to tweak them to accomplish exactly what I want? I've literally spent the past day looking for a fix. Btw I'm using XAMPP on windows 7

Comment: TLDR, but sounds a lit like you are looking for the `QSA` flag for `RewriteRule`s.

Answer (score 0):

When rewriting, the URL sent is not the one used to call your script, but you still have access to the original. In `index.php`, explode `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` on `?`, the first item is your path and with the second (if it exists) `parse_str($exploded[1], $_GET);`

Comment: Hey, can you explain this a bit more? I don't quite understand

Comment: It's a way to get original, uncorrupted `$_GET` variables in a php script that is called from a rewrite. It doesn't have to be `index.php`, you could do this in an include that each page's php file calls.